# Trying to create a web page. Issue with centering text on nav bar

Tags: css, html, webpage-screenshot, pixel-perfect

I am using pixel perfect to try to duplicate a web page for learning purposes. I am having a really hard time trying to create this. For starters, my text will not stay centered on the nav bar. I think it may be an issue with my header. I might have combined the header and nav by accident. I'm not sure how to fix it.

[The page I am trying to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKWC9.png)

My html:

```
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
    <div id="bluebox"><h1>Main Title Here</h1></div>
    <div id="outerbox"></div>
    <div id="navbox"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

My css:

```
/* general */
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font-size: 100%; line-height: 1.5em; font-family: 'arial'; }
article, aside, figure, footer, header, main, menu, nav, section, video {display: block;}

/* wrapper */
#wrapper {width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto; }

/* header */
#wrapper header {height: 50px; padding-top: 128px; padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px;}
#wrapper h1 {font-family: "arial"; color: #FFF; top: 70px; position: absolute; padding-left: 195px; font-size: 2.75em;}
#bluebox{
 background-color: #23b6eb;
 width: 1020px;
 height: 140px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
}
#outerbox{
 background-color: #5d5a5a;
 width: 1020px;
 height: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
}

/* navigation */

#navbox{
 background-color: #BBB;
 width: 1020px;
 height: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 170px;
}

.navigation-bar {display: inline-block; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em; vertical-align: center; text-align: center;}
nav ul li span, nav ul li a {text-decoration: none; color: #000; }
```

Comment: Why are you using `position: absolute`? Your code is so wrong! `:(` Don't use `position: absolute` for whatever reason you have right now. Why? Looks for me is a wrapper with a padding, and background, and then header, content, and footer has the individual colours.

Comment: Yeah I kind of have no idea what I am doing. I never had to create something from scratch before. I still don't know how to fix it

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Same one with the right way. I have changed the following:

1. Completely get rid of the `position: absolute`.
2. Replace all the `height` using `line-height`.
3. Get rid of unnecessary tags, like `outer-box`, etc.
4. Use semantic tags, wherever possible.

```css
/* general */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'arial';
}

article, aside, figure, footer, header, main, menu, nav, section, video {
  display: block;
}

/* wrapper */
#wrapper {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: #5d5a5a;
}

/* header */
#wrapper header {
  background-color: #23b6eb;
}

#wrapper header h1 {
  font-family: "arial";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.75em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5;
}


/* navigation */
nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Main Title Here</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: I tried copying and pasting your code, but it changed all my colors and the layout of the header and nav. It did center my text though, but everything else changed.

Comment: @MollyMarie Can you run the code snippet and put it on the full screen and see if shows the correct expected output? I verified with the image you had given as reference.

Comment: @MollyMarie Make a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) with your current code with mine, I can help you with it. `:)` This is the current version, for your perusal: http://jsbin.com/fekahemura/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @MollyMarie You should be more interested in the `/* navigation */` part of the CSS.

Comment: It worked this time. It looks like yours now, problem is though, it has made my body text all align all the way to left. Not sure why

Comment: @MollyMarie Default alignment is `left`.

Comment: How do I get my body text to go back to center? I'm not sure why that was even affected since we only changed header and the nav

Comment: @MollyMarie Show your current implementation in JSBin and let me know so we can debug it together.